# Php exec not answering correctly

Tags: php, shell, command, exec

after a couple of hours haven't finded my solution.
I'm actually attempted to open a windows program from the PHP exec function.
I can actually get results from "ipconfig" command. All good with it.

My real problem is i can't open up any external programs. Here is my line.

```
exec("start C:/VALOFEEU/CombatArms/CombatArms.exe 2>&1", $output);
print_r($output);
```

$output doesn't return any results from this command.
if you guys know something would be appreciate it.

Comment: When executing the code, does the `CombatArms.exe` starts successfully?

Comment: No, it's seem to do nothing

Comment: What happens if you run the command `start C:/VALOFEEU/CombatArms/CombatArms.exe` in command prompt?

Comment: From the cmd it's working successfully